# How to send an image with an form in http post from ionic to node.js?

Tags: node.js, http, ionic-framework

I want to send image with form data like name and description in http post.

```
var body={
 name:name,
 description:desc
}
this.http.post("url",body).subscribe(val=>{
    console.log(val);
})
```

How can i send an image along with the data in HTTP post ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', imgBlob, filename)
this.http.post('url', formData)
```

Comment: Will there be any change in html part? <input type='file' name='filename />'

Comment: I got it with FormData.

Answer (score 0):

To post an image in angular you need to `append` it in your form data like this

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", this.angForm.get("image").value);
formData.append("name", this.angForm.get("name").value);
formData.append("description", this.angForm.get("desc").value);

this.http.post("url",formData).subscribe(val=>{
     console.log(val);
```

});

Create a function to check the file after changing the input value

```
 onFileSelect(event) {
   if (event.target.files.length > 0) {

    const file = event.target.files[0];


    this.form.get("image").setValue(file);
    //here form is your form that you use like reactive form 
   //set form image value
   }
```