# How to send Angular 6 object with image File to web-api?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to post Image File with other form details as one object as below

```
export interface Employee {
    id: Guid;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    imgFile: File;
    enteredDate: Date;
}
```

This is my service

```
  addEmployee(employee: Employee) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'employees/add', employee);
  }
```

Is it possible to send a File as above ? If possible How to retrieve that file in asp.net core web api ?

```
  [HttpPost("add")]
  public void Add(EmployeeAddDto employeeAddDto)
  {
   ....// save employeeAddDto object to database
  }
```

in `EmployeeAddDto` what should be the file of `imgFile` ?

Comment: You can do that by using `FormData` check this [post-formdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55888670/how-to-send-an-image-with-an-form-in-http-post-from-ionic-to-node-js/55888944#55888944)

Comment: if your web-api only accept json then you not able to send image file as form data or image as json for this you have few options like user web-api with json or formdata type 

or you can first convert image into base64 and then send by json once you get base64 string sever side decode back to image from base64 then i will work

Answer (score 1):

For uploading file, you need to use `formdata` at client side and `FromForm`at server side.

1. Client View

   ```
   <input id="imgFile" type="file" (change)="addFile($event)" placeholder="Upload file">
   ```
2. Client JS

   ```
   public addFile(element) {
           let data = new FormData();
       data.append('firstName', 'f1');
       data.append('lastName', 'l1');
       data.append('imgFile', element.target.files[0]);
       this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/add', data).subscribe(result => {

           });
   }
   ```
3. Server API

   ```
   [HttpPost("add")]
   public void Add([FromForm]EmployeeAddDto employeeAddDto)
   {
   }
   ```
4. Model

   ```
   public class EmployeeAddDto
   {
       public string Id { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public string Email { get; set; }
       public IFormFile ImgFile { get; set; }
       public DateTime EnteredDate { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using dotnet as a backend

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/values/Post")]       
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {      

        foreach (var file in Request.Form.Files)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream());
            \\
            \\your code
            \\
        }
    }
```

in angular use FormData for send image

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use **Form Data** to send both you data Object/Model and the file. The simple trick to do so is just **stringify** your object.
Here is an example

> let formDatavar = new FormData();
> formDatavar.append("File",fileDetails,FileName)
> formDatavar.append("ModelData",JSON.stringify(ModelDataFromUI))

Then you can use the formDatavar to send your data

At last you need to convert your string to object in your backend service